Vercel Auto redirect error after deployment
so i have this application made with next js 14 that i deployed on vercel but i'm facing a problem that i can't understand from where it comes , the build went well and everything works greate without any error when i use vercel random generated websites but once i enter to the same project using my custom domain once i start scrolling at first i'm hiding the navbar and i'm having a section where the data is retrieved from mysql server i don't now exactly which one is responsable about that but once i scroll a little bit the page is redirected automatically to the page /Dashboard that i don't have at all on my project .
i tried building the app locally and it works fine , i also tried to use it on the phone with the same website and it works fine too , but when i try on my laptop it doesn't work properly error.
the good is simple and i don't know if its the reason i think its releated to the custom domain or some settings on the vercel deployment options , if any one had the same problem before please help me.
